# Java Non Blocking Client

Tags: java

I´ve a question concerning non blocking Sockets: I understand how to register for example, two socketchannels for write/read events.

But how does such an event look like? If I want to write some data on SocketChannel1 (for example when I press a button) to a server how can I do this?

All examples I´ve found only deal with the registration of the sockets, like this:
http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/#About%20the%20author

Greetings,

Flo

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the examples which come with the JDK under the `sample` directory.

If you use non blocking IO, you should wait until after you have a write op from the socket to perform the write.  While you are waiting, you can buffer the data.  However, this rarely needed as this is only required when the write buffer of the socket is full (which shouldn't happen very often) and if this is the case for a long period fo time you may deside you have a slow consumer and close the connection instead.

Personally, I wouldn't suggest you use non-blocking NIO directly unless you have a very good understanding of what is going on.  Instead I suggest you use a library like Netty which will handle all the edge cases for you.  Or you could use blocking NIO which is much simpler (and can be faster for a small number of connections)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I understand non-blocking NIO so far, I just wanted to know how can I sag to a certain socketChannel to write a certain array of bytes?